# C# MVC (Visual Studio for Mac): The view 'Login' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, visual-studio-mac

I'm facing what I guess it's a common MVC "View not found" issue, and I was reading some SO threads to no avail, so please don't mark it as duplicate because I'm also working with Visual Studio for Mac, so not sure if this could have something to do.

Login EndPoint in AccountController:

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    AWS_Manager aws = new AWS_Manager(TestController.access_id, TestController.secret_key);
    var result = SignInStatus.Failure;

    UserModels oUser = await Task.Run(() => aws.getUser(model.Email));
    if (oUser != null)
    {
        if (oUser.Password == Crypto.GetSHA1(model.Password) && oUser.testloader_enabled == true)
        {
            SetUser(model.Email);
            result = SignInStatus.Success;
        }
    }

    // No cuenta los errores de inicio de sesión para el bloqueo de la cuenta
    // Para permitir que los errores de contraseña desencadenen el bloqueo de la cuenta, cambie a shouldLockout: true
    // var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

After a successful login everything's go fine and user is redirected to home, but in a non successful login attempt, instead of being redirected to login with the corresponding model error message, the following exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException The view 'Login' or its master was
> not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The
> following locations were searched: ~/Views/Account/Login.aspx
> ~/Views/Account/Login.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx
> ~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx ~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml
> ~/Views/Account/Login.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
> ~/Views/Shared/Login.vbhtml

The weird thing is that ~/Account/login.cshtml **does** exist.

[image]

I tried to explicitly specify the view in the "default" branch of the switch as:

```
return View("Login", model);
```

But the same exception is thrown.

RouteConfig:

using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

```
namespace xxx
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
namespace xxx
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // Para obtener más información para configurar la autenticación, visite http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure el contexto de base de datos, el administrador de usuarios y el administrador de inicios de sesión para usar una única instancia por solicitud
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Permitir que la aplicación use una cookie para almacenar información para el usuario que inicia sesión
            // y una cookie para almacenar temporalmente información sobre un usuario que inicia sesión con un proveedor de inicio de sesión de terceros
            // Configurar cookie de inicio de sesión
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Permite a la aplicación validar la marca de seguridad cuando el usuario inicia sesión.
                    // Es una característica de seguridad que se usa cuando se cambia una contraseña o se agrega un inicio de sesión externo a la cuenta.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });            
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Permite que la aplicación almacene temporalmente la información del usuario cuando se verifica el segundo factor en el proceso de autenticación de dos factores.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Permite que la aplicación recuerde el segundo factor de verificación de inicio de sesión, como el teléfono o correo electrónico.
            // Cuando selecciona esta opción, el segundo paso de la verificación del proceso de inicio de sesión se recordará en el dispositivo desde el que ha iniciado sesión.
            // Es similar a la opción Recordarme al iniciar sesión.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
        }
    }
}
```

I've just migrated this app from Visual Studio for Windows to Visual Studio 2022 for Mac, and I'm quite sure on Windows it just works, but now I'm on my Mac and cannot test it on a Windows machine.

I'm sure it'll end being something stupid, but for the moment I'm stuck.

Comment: I recommend reading Microsoft's documentation about [View Discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#view-discovery). But you should be able get it working by either creating another Login endpoint for a HttpGet request that returns your viewmodel on a redirect OR specifing an absolute path to your file, like: "return View("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml");". Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Blazorman. It's definitely weird, but now I know it's something related to the fact I'm running Visual Studio 2022 for Mac (I've clearly given this info in the question title). I copied my entire solution to my Windows laptop and I the issue does not happen, so, as you see in not a problem that I'm missunderstanding how views are searched, but something related to VS2022 for Mac. BTW, I obviously tried your suggestion, but it also fails on my VS for MacOS.